# Edit large geojson data sets in Openlayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, editing

I'd like to edit a rather large collection (several MB of polygons and lines) with OpenLayers.

What's the best way working with large data sets, considering client side (rendering) performance and server side scalability?

We're currently using Geoserver on the backend side, though in order to enable scalable editing capabilities we're also looking into other directions.

EDIT

I should add a bit more background. I expect lots of geometries, even when zoomed in. Consider very large venues where there are hundreds of stands / booths, besides also other indoor (floors and others) and outdoor (building) geometries.

Comment: WFS-T is probably the way forward, have you investigated this already?

Answer (score 3):

We faced similar problem. We consider to implement as following.

Displaying all of the data served by GeoServer as WMS and loading vector data filtered by distance parameter seems to work. I mean WMS layer will show all data, rendering several MBs of data is not an issue for GeoServer. And only features within given distance will be loaded as vector (say features that are closer than 100 meters to the center of the map).

Since vector data is limited client side will not have performance issues.

Vector data can be loaded as WFS-T. OL has capabilities to edit WFS-T, here is an example https://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/openlayers-editing-wfs-t/.

I'd be pleased to read alternative approaches.

Comment: I should add to my question that I'll certainly have lots of data even in a small view. This is for indoor / venue applications, where for example there will be hundred+ stands / booths and other geometries in a single view when zoomed in.

Comment: You can load just a single view(say it has thousand stands/booths) that is closest one to the center of  map view. I think that OL can handle thousand geometries. If center of the map changes(i.e. dragend event occurs) you may reload data.OR alternatively you may have a button for reloading data for editing. If still performance is not satisfying(thousand features may slow down OL, I'm not sure), you may add form where user may enter attribute(id or name of the feature that will be edited) and load just the features that have that attribute.